# How I contact with SSH?

Tags: networking, ssh, settings

I want to connect to RPI with SSH but my computer has one network and my router has another network?
I try to connect and it gives me this error:
[image: error]

Maybe I need to change the settings? And what?

It is very urgent to me,
Thanks!

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead

Comment: The ssh server is not running on the machine you try to connect to.